# Spring Service to talk to another Spring service

Tags: json, spring, rest, service

I am new to Spring boot and was wondering how to have services talk to another service.

I am making a wholesale order json and the information would go to both a billing log and an item repository. I have a Controller and a Service to receive the wholesale order, but how do I add it to both those repositories? Billing Log and Item have Controller -> Service -> Repository. I was thinking to make the service object static so I can call the service by the controller, but have seen that it could be a bad idea. Is there a general way on how to make spring services talk to each other to save in their respective repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted a Service to modify a repository that is within another Service. I solved this by autowiring public static services in the main application of spring-boot. This allows services to call other service's public methods

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to save data in two different tables through two different services.
If so, first check if there is a relationship between these two entities. If so, you can use JPA cascades to make a single save that does all the work. If not, you can inject one service into another then call the the appropriate save method for your second entity.
You can also as a last choice inject several repositories in a single service then save your second entity directly from its repository.